# SQL Server Creating complicated SQL Query for 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me creating this SQL query for SQL Server 2008.

I've wasted 1 day thinking of this but I cannot find the solution:

I have 3 [tables] with respective (columns):

- `[table_users]` TB1 `(Id, Name)`
- `[table_schedule]` TB2 `(Id, userId, dateScheduled)`
- `[table_schedule_confirmation]` TB3 `(Id, scheduleId, confirmationStatus)`

  confirmationStatus -> 0 = cancelled, 1 = confirmed

I must filter `[TB1]` by selecting a day, it must list only user names that:

- are not scheduled at all (`userId` doesn't exist in `[TB2]` for selected day)

or

- if scheduled, there's a matching confirmation for (`scheduleId`) in `[TB3]` and
  (`confirmationStatus`) must be 0 (cancelled)

Problems:

- There can be more than one entries in `TB2` and `TB3` for a `userId` and date

Date Filter = 31/03/2013

Situation 1 (1 confirmed schedule):

[Situation1 http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/1508/sqld.png](http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/1508/sqld.png)

As you can see, I've scheduled 4 times for user 1, but he cancelled the 3 first, confirming only on the 4th time.

Situation 2 (1 pending schedule):

[Situation1 http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/8116/sql2s.png](http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/8116/sql2s.png)

In this case, user hasn't confirmed the 4th (id=16) schedule yet.

Situation 3 (all schedules cancelled):

[Situation1 http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/5720/sql3s.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/5720/sql3s.png)

User cancelled all the 4 schedules.

Situation 4 (no schedules for user on that date):

[Situation1 http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/9679/sql4.png](http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/9679/sql4.png)

No schedules for selected day.

In resume:

Filtering by date, I must list only users that applies to Situations 3 and 4 and NOT applies to Situations 1 and 2 !

I must make this filter, to populate a dropdown with only users that are available for that day.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
DECLARE @dataAg datetime SET @dataAg = '2013/03/31 16:30'

SELECT T1.id, T1.name 
FROM [tbl_users] T1
WHERE
    (NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT * 
          FROM [tbl_schedule] T2 
          WHERE T2.userId = T1.id 
          AND CONVERT(date,T2.scheduledDate) = CONVERT(date, @dataAg))
    )
    OR
    (EXISTS
         (SELECT * 
          FROM [tbl_schedule] T2, [tbl_scheduleConfirmation] T3 
          WHERE T2.id = T3.idSchedule 
            AND T2.userId = T1.id 
            AND CONVERT(date,T2.scheduledDate) = CONVERT(date, @dataAg))
     AND
     NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT * 
           FROM [tbl_schedule] T2, [tbl_scheduleConfirmation] T3 
           WHERE T2.id = T3.idSchedule 
             AND T3.confirmation = 1 
             AND T2.idUser = T1.id 
             AND CONVERT(date, T2.scheduledDate) = CONVERT(date, @dataAg))
          )
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it.

```
DECLARE @dataAg datetime SET @dataAg = '2013/03/31 16:30'

SELECT T1.id, T1.name FROM [tbl_users] T1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM [tbl_schedule] T2 WHERE T2.userId = T1.id AND CONVERT(date,T2.scheduledDate) = CONVERT(date,@dataAg)
    )
OR
(
NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM [tbl_schedule] T2 WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT * FROM [tbl_scheduleConfirmation] T3 WHERE T2.id = T3.idSchedule 
        )
        AND T2.userId = T1.id AND CONVERT(date,T2.scheduledDate) = CONVERT(date,@dataAg)
    )
AND
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM [tbl_schedule] T2, [tbl_scheduleConfirmation] T3 WHERE 
    T2.id = T3.idSchedule AND T3.confirmation = 1 AND T2.userId = T1.id AND CONVERT(date,T2.scheduledDate) = CONVERT(date,@dataAg)
    )
)
```

Thank's anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all the columns in TB1 this query should get you what you need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB1 
WHERE ID IN 
      (SELECT ID 
       FROM TB3 
       WHERE confirmationStatus = 1 
         AND scheduleID IN 
             (SELECT ID 
              FROM TB2 
              WHERE DATE(dateScheduled) = 'YOUR_ENTERED_DATE'))
```

In the future, you may also want to include what exactly you are using (mySQL, SQL Server, etc.)

Comment: Thank you David, but i don't think this would do the job. Seems to be a little more complicated.

Comment: Help us understand what you are asking for by using pseudocode.  You want all the data in `TB1` where the `user` has a `confirmed scheduling` on a `date that you specify`?

Comment: I want to list all users (id + name) from TB1 that are "available" for a specified date...

By "available" i mean:
- There's no entry with this date + userId on TB2 at all
OR
- if there's one or more entries for this date + userId on TB2, all of these entries must have a corresponding row in TB3 (cancelling or confirming)
AND
- none of the corresponding entries in TB3 have "confirmation = 1"

Comment: in another words:

- This user was never scheduled for that day
OR
- If he was scheduled for that day, he must have confirmed or cancelled the schedule, if he didn't replied the scheduled yet then he must not be listed as we don't know if he will be available
AND
- There must not be any entry in TB3 for this date + user that is confirmed